# Stability and the Hilbert Polynomial of an Image

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, geometric-invariant-theory

In Huybrechts and Lehn it says that for two semistable sheaves $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}$ and a sheaf homomorphism $f : \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{G}$, writing $$\mathcal{E} := \text{im}(f)$$ yields the inequality $$p(\mathcal{F}) \leq p(\mathcal{E}) \leq p(\mathcal{G}),$$
where $p(-)$ denotes taking the Hilbert polynomial. I understand why $p(\mathcal{E}) \leq p(\mathcal{G})$; it is because $\mathcal{G}$ is semistable and $\mathcal{E}$ is a subsheaf of it.

Yet, I do not see why $p(\mathcal{F}) \leq p(\mathcal{E})$. In fact, I am so clueless that I see the opposite! For considering the exact sequence $$0 \to \text{ker}(f) \to \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{E} \to 0$$ we get $p(\mathcal{F}) = p(\text{ker}(f))+ p(\mathcal{E})$ and so $p(\mathcal{E}) \leq p(\mathcal{F})$ by positivity of the coefficients of the Hilbert Polynomial.

Comment: With the notations as in Huybrechts and Lehn: $p(-)$ is *reduced* Hilbert polynomial, i.e. $p(\mathcal{E},m):= \frac{P(\mathcal{E},m)}{\alpha_d(\mathcal{E})}$, where $d=\text{dim}(\mathcal{E})$ and $P(\mathcal{E},m)$ is the Hilbert polynomial of $\mathcal{E}$. Unlike Hilbert polynomial, reduced Hilbert polynomial is not additive. And $p(\mathcal{F})\leq p(\mathcal{E})$ also follows from the fact that $\mathcal{F}$ is semi-stable (see the equivalent definition of semi-stability; it was proved in the said book).